# Dual Display Issue with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a couple-year-old Dell Inspiron desktop and figured I'd give myself a treat and upgrade to dual monitors. Up until now I had been using the integrated graphics (Intel HD 530) but figured I'd throw a graphics card (AMD R5 220, using opensource Radeon driver) in so I could use HDMI for both monitors. After updating the BIOS settings to keep the integrated graphics active I was able to boot into Ubuntu.

However, while I was able to boot to the encryption unlock page with no problem, once I get to the login page things get strange. On the login page, I don't see any text next to the user profiles, just the profile icons (ie. no username is displayed). I can still attempt to login but when I type in my password it either a)gives an error (it tries to render text but it only does every other letter or so) or b)just stops and prompts me for the password again.

Everything works fine when running on **either** the discrete AMD card **or** the integrated graphics. The issue only presents itself when both monitors are plugged into both graphics options. Knowing this, I have tried to boot with only one monitor plugged in and then adding in the second one after getting to the desktop. When I do this, it hangs for a minute, the screen does some crazy flashes, and I get logged out with the same issue as above and get thrown into a login loop.

Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this or what could fix it? Thanks in advanced!

Results from running `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|Display'`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
Subsystem: Dell HD Graphics 530
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Caicos [Radeon HD 6450/7450/8450 / R5 230 OEM]
Subsystem: XFX Pine Group Inc. Caicos [Radeon HD 6450/7450/8450 / R5 230 OEM]
Kernel driver in use: radeon
Kernel modules: radeon
```

## EDIT

It seems that logging in using Wayland instead of Xorg solves all issues I was experiencing. I would think the more mature Xorg would handle a relatively older graphics card better than the newer Wayland. Does anyone have any thoughts as to why this could be?